# How to display MXGraph Vertices above Edges?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I'm doing some work with MX Graph to help identify critical content paths through a website. I have it set up so each vertex represents a page on the website and each edge represents a group of visitors that traveled from page A to page B.

Everything is working well except there are so many edges I can't see the most popular vertices. Is there a way to layer the edges below the vertices? I tried using the basic layering system but that seemed to break the fast organic layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
mxGraph.prototype.ordered = false;
```